# Spark Data frame throwing error when trying to query nested column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a Dataframe with below schema. This is basically an XML file, which I have converted to Dataframe for further processing. I trying to extract **_Date** column, but looks like some type mismatch is happening

```
df1.printSchema

 |-- PlayWeek: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TicketSales: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PlayDate: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- BoxOfficeDetail: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- VisualFormatCd: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Code: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _SequenceId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _SessionTypeCd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _TicketPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _TicketQuantity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _TicketTax: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _TicketTypeCd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _FilmId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _Screen: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _TheatreId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _BusinessEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _BusinessStartDate: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to extract **_Date** column but its throwing below error

```
scala> df1.select(df1.col("PlayWeek.TicketSales.PlayDate._Date")).show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'PlayWeek.TicketSales.PlayDate[_Date]' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, '_Date' is of string type.;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:334)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may give you some clues: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13623